# Can-bus Filter and Mask Logic

Tags: c, can-bus

I want to understand below code, why the filter 0x100 between 1xFF address.
Mask value is 1110000000000000 (16 bit) and filter value is 10000000000000. That mean my ids could be **100**100000000000(16bit),**100**00100000000(16 bit) etc. (**100**.. side must be constant all ids.

But the 0x100 value is 100000000 (9 bit) how this possible I can not understand.How it compares 9-bit and 16-bit id ?

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef CAN_Filter_Init(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcanxx)
{
  CAN_FilterTypeDef can_filter_config;
  //100 to 1FF in other words block all messages after 0x0200
  can_filter_config.FilterActivation = CAN_FILTER_ENABLE;
  can_filter_config.FilterBank = 0;
  can_filter_config.FilterIdHigh = 0x100 << 5;
  // can_filter_config.FilterIdHigh = 0x000;

  can_filter_config.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
  can_filter_config.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
  can_filter_config.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  can_filter_config.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x700 << 5;
  // can_filter_config.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0X000;
  can_filter_config.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
  can_filter_config.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FILTER_FIFO0;
  can_filter_config.SlaveStartFilterBank = 0;

  if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(hcanxx, &can_filter_config) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

Comment: Your CAN mask and filter should be 11 Bit (Base frame) or 29 Bit (Extended frame).

Comment: with the intention of learning its reason, where do you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CAN bus has 11-bit identifiers ([base frame format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Base_frame_format)) and 29-bit identifiers ([extended frame format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Extended_frame_format)).

So if `FilterIdHigh` is 16 bits, and the 11-bit identifier is in the upper bits of the register, then you need to left shift the identifier by 5 bits to put it into the 11 MSBs of the register. That is why the code has the left shift (`<< 5`) for both the `FilterIdHigh` and the `FilterMaskIdHigh`.

The 0x100 value isn't a 9-bit value, it's an 11-bit value `001 0000 0000`.
The mask 0x700 value is also an 11-bit value `111 0000 0000`.

As a result, the upper three bits of the 11-bit identifier must be 001, and any identifier of the form
 `001 xxxx xxxx` will pass the filter. So identifiers from 0x100 thru 0x1ff will pass the filter.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you talk about the FilterMode IDlist description?

Comment: @CKocar It would be best to start a new question. I'm not familiar with the FilterMode IDlist.